# Node.js What happens when 2 persons access the same application and declare the same variable?

Tags: node.js

What happens when 2 users are accessing my web app through their browser and declare the same variable just seconds away from each other? Example:

I have a page that loads values from the database to a variable like this:

```
var details = packageInfo.findOne({where: {packageId: x.packageId}, include: [{ model: user}]});
```

So the sequence is as follows:

1. User A accesses the application through their browser and the above line of code is executed.  Now the `details` variable has a value from the database based on their ID.
2. User B accesses the same application and the same code gets executed just seconds after the user A, now `details` variable has a different value.
3. When user A, while using the application, `details` variable gets called because it is needed to retrieve some data related to user A.

The question is, will `details` variable will have their data or user B's data?

Comment: It depends on weather `details` is a global or local variable. If the line of code is inside a function then `details` is local which means hat user A will have a `details` variable and user B will have a completely different variable that happens to have the same name `details`. There are two objects in memory - not one

Comment: Is that variable global? If it's not, then there is no concurrency problem.

Comment: I am new to nodejs. all of the variables are inside function, nothing is declared globally.  is it better to save all the variables in req.session (as best practices) ??

Answer (score 0):

depends how you implemented it :

**case one - usually**
your `details` variable is declared inside a function that is called when users connect

```js
app.get("/route", function (req, res) {
  var details = packageInfo.findOne({where: {packageId: x.packageId}, include: [{ model: user}]});
  //do stuff
}
```

this is the right way of doing it and here each users will have a different *details* variable

**case two - not good**
your variable is declared globally and changed by users actions locally

```js
var details;

app.get("/route", function (req, res) {
  details = packageInfo.findOne({where: {packageId: x.packageId}, include: [{ model: user}]})
  //do stuff
}
```

here you will have a problem because *details* is overwritten by each user ...

Comment: I am new to nodejs.  is it usually as best paractices to strore the variables in req.session (as session variables)?